# Google Sheets Hierarchical Category/Sub-Category Display Formula

Tags: google-sheets

I have a table of data such as

```
A       B    C
Cat    Fur   25
Snake  Fur   10
       Fur   11
       Coat  9
```

In another sheet, I wanted Column A to factor in the categories above such that it outputs the following:

```
A        B
Fur      11
  Cat    25
  Snake  10
Coat     9
```

I can't use a Pivot Table to do this and am trying to avoid a [custom function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions), but will do a custom function if I have to.  I am a little lost on how I can have Column A appear using a formula and, even better, indents.

Comment: Why can't you use a pivot table? That's exactly what pivot tables do. If you use Google Sheets, please don't tag with Excel. There is a difference.

Comment: On "to avoid a function", are you referring to [custom functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/function) or  [built-in functions](https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273?hl=en)?

Comment: @teylyn if I use a Pivot Table, the Fur row would return the total of Cat + Snake (e.g. 35) instead of returning the actual value of 11.  If there's a way around that, then I can use a pivot table.

Comment: @Rubén I was referring to custom functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did manage to achieve the appearance of your table with repeated sorting:

```
=ArrayFormula(filter(if(sort(A:A,B:B&A:A,true)="",sort(B:C,B:B&A:A,true),sort({"  "&A:A,C:C},B:B&A:A,true)),sort(B:B,B:B&A:A,true)<>""))
```

[image]

except that Coat appears before Fur because they are sorted alphabetically.

The issue here was that if I had sorted by column B then column A separately, the rows with a blank in column A would have appeared last in each group which is not what OP asked for. The workaround was to concatenate each cell in column B with the corresponding cell in column A and sort on the resulting values (FurCat, FurSnake, Fur and Coat) so that the list was in the correct order (Coat, Fur, FurCat and FurSnake).

Answer (score 0):

If your pivot table does not return the result you want, then your data source is not structured correctly.

Furr has the value of 11 as a sub category of animal, where it is NOT snake and NOT cat, but blank.

[image]